# How to run a CLI command from Go?

Tags: command-line, go, terminal, gulp

How do I run a Gulp task from a Go program?

This is the command I run from a typical terminal:

```
gulp serv.dev
```

How could I run this simple line of code from golang:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // What do I put here to open terminal in background and run `gulp serv.dev`?
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you're looking for is [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)

You'll pretty much want to spawn off a process that will run your `gulp` task.

This can be done like so:

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("gulp", "serv.dev")
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Output). For your use case:

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("gulp", "serv.dev").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need [exec package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)

```
cmd := exec.Command("gulp", "serv.dev")
err := cmd.Run()
```

Take a look at example at [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command). They explained how to pass parameters and read the output.

Answer (score 1):

---

More generic, better output.

---

Use the **exec.Command**, along with **buffers** to record output and display it only when useful.

You can even make the function work with any command by using **variadic arguments**, aka arguments of an arbitrary quantity of elements.

Label **unhanded errors** appropriately, so if a command fails you are told which one and why.

Lastly note that Go, although expressive, is a quite **raw language**. It holds your hand for nothing. You will have to program plenty by yourself.

---

Example **code**:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    runCommand(currentFunction(), "ping", "-c1", "google.commm")
}

func commandErrorMessage(stderr bytes.Buffer, program string) string {
    message := string(stderr.Bytes())

    if len(message) == 0 {
        message = "the command doesn't exist: " + program + "\n"
    }

    return message
}

func currentFunction() string {
    counter, _, _, success := runtime.Caller(1)

    if !success {
        println("functionName: runtime.Caller: failed")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    return runtime.FuncForPC(counter).Name()
}

func printCommandError(stderr bytes.Buffer, callerFunc string, program string, args ...string) {
    printCommandErrorUbication(callerFunc, program, args...)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s", commandErrorMessage(stderr, program))
}

func printCommandErrorUbication(callerFunc string, program string, args ...string) {
    format := "error at: %s: %s %s\n"
    argsJoined := strings.Join(args, " ")
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, format, callerFunc, program, argsJoined)
}

func runCommand(callerFunc string, program string, args ...string) {
    command := exec.Command(program, args...)
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    command.Stderr = &stderr
    fail := command.Run()

    if fail != nil {
        printCommandError(stderr, callerFunc, program, args...)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

---

Example **run**:

```
$ go run test.go
error at: main.main: ping -c1 google.commm
ping: google.commm: Name or service not known
exit status 1
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave a small example for those who are going to run a binary:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"

)

func main() {
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    exPath := filepath.Dir(ex)

    var command = path.Join(exPath, "libexec")
    os := runtime.GOOS
    switch os {
    case "windows":
        command += ".exe"
    case "darwin":
        command += ""
    case "linux":
        command = "." + command
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%s.\n", os)
    }
    // it lacks to implement a check if the executable exists or
    // is in one of the path variables
    out, err := exec.Command(command).Output()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Out: %s", out)

}
```

- [os/exec](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) - used to get the current executable directory
- [runtime](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime) - used to get arch
- [path](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath) - used to mount libexec path